# Semi-metric space with convergence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be a metrical space. Let $B(X)$ be the set of nonempty, bounded subsets of $X$. Define a semi-metrics on $B(X)$ ($0$ distance can exist) which inducates this convergence:
$A_n\rightarrow A$, if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N$ such that for every $n>N$, $A_n\subset A_\epsilon$ and $A\subseteq (A_n)_\epsilon$,
where $H_c$ means the open sets with radius $c$ neighbourhood.

Let $K(X)$ be the set of nonempty, compact subsets of $X$. Show that the prevously defined semi-metrics is a metrics on $K(X)$ and if $X$ is complete, then the defined metric space is complete.

I believe the first part of this question is rather easy, still I was not able to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a metric space $(X,d)$, as I understood your notation the required convergence is provided by [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) $d_H$, [whose restriction on $K(X)$ is a metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#Properties) and this is proved in Proposition 2-2 of [H]. When $(X, d)$ is complete, then $(K(X), d_H)$ is complete, and this is proved in Theorem 3-3 of [H].

*References*

[H] Jeff Henrikson, *[Completeness and total boundedness of the Hausdorff metric](https://web.archive.org/web/20020623095720/http://www-math.mit.edu/phase2/UJM/vol1/HAUSF.PDF)*, MIT Undergraduate Journal of Mathematics, 1999 69–80.